# Calculate sum using sum api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatables

I've been trying to calculate the sum of my columns using the sum API, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm using data-order to insert into DataTables my numeric values.

```
<td data-order="12345.123'"> $ 12 345,123 </td>
```

[I've tried this but it doesn't work](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html) :

```
       "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        var A = api.column( 1 ).data();

        var B = api.column( 2 ).data();

        var C = api.column( 3 ).data();

        $( api.column( 0 ).footer() ).html(A);
        $( api.column( 1 ).footer() ).html(B);
        $( api.column( 2 ).footer() ).html(C);
        $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(D);
    }
```

Any idea why? Here, I'm not using the reduce function as normally the data is inside data-order and doesn't need to be filtered (is the data really being taken from data-order in this case? Anyways even with the reduce function it doesn't work...)

I've also read that we can use this but after [trial and error](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42217/calculating-column-total-with-currency-data) I can't seem to figure out how :

```
table.cells( null, columnnum ).render( 'order' )
```

Can somebody please enlighten me as to why this doesn't work? Am I missing something? I'm fairly new to the DataTables plugin :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `table.cells( null, columnnum ).render('sort')` - that forum post you referred to was wrong,  it's just been updated. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Colin is everywhere :) Thanks!

Comment: Yw, you can't get away from me ;)